# Tailwind grid-rows-2 generating 3 rows

Tags: css, reactjs

My grid-rows-2 property is generating for some reason 3 rows.

Code in the picture:

[image: Result and code on the right]

Comment: could you provide code in "https://play.tailwindcss.com/"?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `w-1/3` class in each child element

Comment: I still don't get the desired output because my Childs are stacked in one col - I would like them to be 2 child on the left side and 1 child on the right side of the parent div.

Comment: then use nested grid like inside child give another grid and divide that again in child

Answer (score 0):

That's the actual behavior of css-grid. In the case of more elements than your defined grid-rows-{x}, grid-auto-rows will automatically fill them with new rows within your container when there are more elements than you specified in the grid-rows.

In your case, you can solve your problem using nested grids

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issues reading this post - this is what resolved my problem:

using the flex property in the parent div and using the ml-auto and mr-auto properties in the child divs to set them manually to the left and right.